# Spark Hashing TF power of two feature dimension recommendation reasoning

Tags: apache-spark, tf-idf

According to https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-features.html#tf-idf:

*"HashingTF utilizes the hashing trick. A raw feature is mapped into an index (term) by applying a hash function. The hash function used here is MurmurHash 3."
...
"Since a simple modulo on the hashed value is used to determine the vector index, it is advisable to use a power of two as the feature dimension, otherwise the features will not be mapped evenly to the vector indices."*

I tried to understand why using a power of two as the feature dimension will map words evenly and tried find some helpful documentation on the internet to understand it, but both attempts were not successful.

Does somebody know or have useful sources on why using the power two maps words evenly to vector indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The output of a hash function is `b`-bit, i.e., there are `2^b` possible values to which a feature can be hashed.  Additionally, we assume that the `2^b` possible values appear uniformly at random.*

If `d` is the feature dimension, an index for a feature `f` is determined as `hash(f) MOD d`.  Again, `hash(f)` takes on `2^b` possible values.  It is easy to see that `d` has to be a power of two (i.e., a divisor of `2^b`) itself in order for *uniformity to be maintained*.

For a counter-example, consider a 2-bit hash function and a 3-dimensional feature space.  As per our assumptions, the hash function outputs 0, 1, 2, or 3 with probability 1/4 each.  However, taking mod 3 results in 0 with probability **1/2**, or 1 or 2 with probability **1/4** each.  Therefore, uniformity is not maintained.  On the other hand; if the feature space were 2-dimensional, it is easy to see that the result would be 0 or 1 with probability 1/2 each.